# Javascript: I need a good data structure to keep a sorted list

Tags: javascript, data-structures, sortedlist

This would probably be implemented as a tree or something?  My point is it needs to be efficient.

I don't know where to find good implementations of data structures for Javascript for something like this, though.  I don't want to have to roll my own if I can avoid it.

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depends why you need it. For instance, if you only need the top element, this [binary heap](http://eloquentjavascript.net/appendix2.html) might be okay for you. Otherwise, implement a binarySearch and insertSorted functions for arrays, should not be more than ten-fifteen lines. Unless you plan on having thousands upon thousands of elements; then it makes more sense to just insert in bulk and then sort using the builtin.

Comment: Having thousands of elements, still binary heap makes more sense than using sort.

Comment: @MartinSeydo I may not have been clear: if you only have intermittent bulk inserts and your array is small enough, sort makes more sense (given that sort is a builtin, and the small scale and low frequency keep the sorting overhead small). If you have repeated inserts, or if the array is large, heap makes more sense (since sort, even though written in native code, would be doing a lot of useless work to just sort for the sake of a single element).

Answer (score 3):

How about a simple array, sorted after each update?

Comment: That would get expensive I think.

Comment: I would think an [insertion sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort) wouldn't get too expensive.

Comment: Unless you have a very large array (or insert a heck of a lot), it should be trivial. If it IS very large, or inserted to a lot, I would be wondering why on earth you need to.

Comment: Yeah, but simply saying 'web application' doesn't say anything about the scale of usage. I can have a web application that lets you add friends to a sorted list that may need to handle 5 names at once, or an app that lets you manage all employees in a corporation of 5,000... bit of a difference in scale. EDIT... ok so you added 'long lists of data'... but how long is long? And how often?

Comment: EDIT: Actually it might be relevant.  Long is potentially thousands, and often is as often as a user would interact with the lists, which is frequently.

Comment: Of course it's relevant. There's always an implementation, maintenance, and performance (in this case, bandwidth) implication of including third party code - especially when it's not part of a well supported framework, in lieu of using a much simpler, though maybe slightly less efficient implementation (assuming it's not TOO inefficient), and using the more complex solution would be an example of premature optimization.

Comment: +1.  To test this I built a JavaScript object analogous to C#'s SortedList which I used as a benchmark on the same machine.  I tried adding 100,000 members both in best possible and worst possible key order.  In IE this took 20s/2s (avg 11sec).  In FF it took 3s/1s (avg 2sec).  In Chrome it took 2s/1s (avg 2sec).  In native C# code, it took 11s/~0s (avg 5sec).  I don't think any of these average insertion times are that bad and they all rival the native C# application (except IE9).  Hans, I would have chosen your answer.