# Locale string comparison does not work properly in Firefox extension web worker

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, web-worker

The `localeCompare()` function does not behave the same in a Firefox extension main code and in a web worker (or chrome worker).

For instance, in the main code, I have this code:

```
var array = ["École", "Frère", "frère", "école"];
array.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.localeCompare(b);
});

console.log('Main: ' + array);
```

it shows:

```
Main: �cole,�cole,Fr�re,fr�re
```

Which is the right sorting (the encoding is not my problem).

In the worker, I have this code:

```
var array = ["École", "Frère", "frère", "école"];
array.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.localeCompare(b);
});

self.postMessage(array);
```

it prints:

```
Frère,frère,école,�0cole
```

which is in the wrong order (once again, the encoding is not my problem).

The sorting in the main code is ok, but not the one in the web worker.

I tried to change the options of the `localeCompare()` function in the web worker, but it does not change anything.

Why is the sorting different in the web worker and how to get it right in the web worker?

(For some reason, I could not send the data to the main code, do the sorting and send it back to the web worker. I still got the wrong order (gives me `école,�0cole,Frère,frère`).)

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I have a likely answer for your "why" question (locale callbacks aren't set in the worker context, `new Date().toLocaleDateString()` probably doesn't work correctly either). If I'm right, it's a JS engine issue however and there isn't much you can do about it - other than filing a bug.

Comment: Note: This looks very much like https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=616841 but that bug was fixed long time ago. And that bug actually added a unit test to verify that `String.localeCompare()` works correctly in web workers.

Comment: `new Date().toLocaleString()` gives me `mer 15 mai 2013 13:18:58 EDT` in both the main code and in the worker. So the locale seems to work in the worker (at least for dates). What most puzzle me is that I cannot send the array to the main code and sort it there. Do you know why I cannot do that? Thanks.

Comment: I'm seeing the same problem, in both Firefox and Chrome. They seem to be using a different (older?) function in the web-workers than they are in the regular browser. Did you find/file a bug for this anywhere? I'd like to follow it if you did.

Comment: I didn't. I'll probably use another solution than web worker.

Answer (score 1):

`localeCompare` is still broken in Firefox Web Workers.
Wladimir mentioned [Bug 616841](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=616841), which indeed fixed it almost everywhere... except for web workers, which were left broken because the Intl backend was (is?) not thread-safe, or some other thread-safety issues. The corresponding "Dead end" patch was never reviewed nor checked in.

I now filed [Bug 903780](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=903780), with a test case based on your code, so that `localeCompare` hopefully will be fixed in the future.