# Intl.Collator and natural sort with numeric option sorts incorrectly with decimal numbers

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-intl

Sorting decimal numbers using `Intl.Collator` and the option to enable `numeric` compares decimals incorrectly.

On some browsers comparing "0.005" and "0.05" returns "0" as in the numbers are the same.

Results in different browsers:

- Chrome 54 = 0
- Firefox 49 = 0
- Edge = -1
- IE 11 = -1

```js
// Returns 0
console.log(new Intl.Collator(undefined, { numeric: true}).compare(0.000005, 0.05))
```

Anyone that can tell me whats wrong?

Reported as bug in Firefox: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1312388

Comment: i get -1 on edge.

Comment: Thanks @NinaScholz, I have updated the question with the different results I get.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As André Bargull observes in [the Firefox bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1312388), numeric sorting considers *only* decimal digit sequences, i.e. in the Unicode category of Number, by their numeric values.  That is, when comparing two otherwise-identical strings containing decimal numbers with fractional components, the entire decimal numbers aren't considered for their numeric value -- because U+002E FULL STOP isn't in the Number category (it's instead in the Punctuation category).

So then, when we compare these two strings -- "0.05" and "0.000005" -- we effectively are comparing these arrays of elements:

```
["0", ".", "05"]
["0", ".", "000005"]
```

and then when digit sequences are considered by their numeric values, we're comparing

```
[0, ".", 5]
[0, ".", 5]
```

which are equal, and so `compare` should return 0 when comparing them.  Firefox and Chrome are right here, and IE and Edge are mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

**Workaround**

Multiply values by 100_000_000 to get rid of decimals

```js
const a = 0.000005;
const b = 0.05;

// NOTE: assume this value is ok for now but prefer
// to get the length of the smallest value and use
// this value in the powers of 10
// for example, [0,09, 0,003] => Math.pow(10, 3)
// But in this case we can go beyond the Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER
const NORMALIZE_VALUE = 100_000_000;

const normalizedA = a * NORMALIZE_VALUE;
const normalizedB = b * NORMALIZE_VALUE;

console.log(new Intl.Collator(undefined, { numeric: true}).compare(normalizedA, normalizedB));
```