# How to overload comparator to sort with UTF-8 and different locales

Tags: javascript, sorting, backbone.js, utf-8, locale

I have a collection of data:

```
["Alphabet","Zend","Ćwiczenia"]
```

as result `collection.sort` I get: `["Alphabet","Zend","Ćwiczenia"]`.

**How to overload `comparator` to sort with UTF-8 and different locales?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set up a [comparator method](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-comparator) on your collection that uses [`localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) as its sort function.

Assuming your collection looks like

```
var c = new C([
    {name: "Alphabet"},
    {name: "Zend"},
    {name: "Ćwiczenia"}
]);
```

it would look like

```
var C = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    comparator: function(a, b) {
        return a.get('name').localeCompare(b.get('name'));
    }
});
```

and a demo

```js
var C = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    comparator: function(a, b) {
        return a.get('name').localeCompare(b.get('name'));
    }
});

var c = new C([
    {name: "Alphabet"},
    {name: "Zend"},
    {name: "Ćwiczenia"}
]);
console.log(c.pluck('name'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.2.3/backbone-min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Great its works. But have other problem. The time of sort with default comparator is 0,5s , but with your comparator ~4s. Its 
a way to speed up the process ?

Comment: You'll have to look up how to speed up locale sorts in JS. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14677060/400x-sorting-speedup-by-switching-a-localecompareb-to-ab-1ab10 could get you started

Comment: @ThePrzemyslaw94 I would recommend that you define a [Collator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Collator) before you define your Backbone.Collection. Something like: `var collator = new Intl.Collator(navigator.language, { sensitivity: 'base' })`. Then inside your comparator function you'd do: `return collator.compare(a.get('name'), b.get('name'))`

Comment: @idbehold,@nikoshr  --Firstly thanks to help me.  I try this method but compare to put on ice my select for over 4 second and page dont works . Maybe a way to asynchronic sort ?