# How to sort an array by UTF-8 in browser Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, utf-8

MDN states that Array.prototype`.sort()` sorts by UTF-16.

"The default sort order is ascending [...] comparing their sequences of UTF-16 code units values."

I need to sort by UTF-8 (or Unicode or UTF-32 as their order is the same).  Is there a good way to do this in the browser?

[UTF-16 maddeningly has some points out of order](https://icu-project.org/docs/papers/utf16_code_point_order.html). That source suggests a  "fix-up" rotation of the out-of-order code points, but I've not seen this widely acknowledged or implemented in the Javascript world.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to overload comparator to sort with UTF-8 and different locales](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41242116/how-to-overload-comparator-to-sort-with-utf-8-and-different-locales)

Comment: While on the topic of the issues with Javascript and UTF-16: JSON requires UTF-8 encoding. Early JSON RFCs (like 4627, 7159) permitted UTF-8, UTF-16, or UTF-32.  The latest JSON RFC 8259, published in 2017, [requires only UTF-8](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8259#section-8).

Comment: You can do this with `Buffer.from`, `Array.prototype.sort`, and `Buffer.compare`, if you’re using Node.js.

Answer (score 1):

To do that you would have to write your own sorting method, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6909126/javascript-sort-with-unicode).

But JS has no built-in UTF-8 sorting method, and I couldn't find any libraries.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative you can use `localCompare` to be able to sort on languages based on UTF-8 if you know it. In the example below I used the Swedish locale 'sv'

```js
const items = ["äng", "ang", "ost", "öst", "zen"];
items.sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b, "sv"));
console.log(items)
```

Reference
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare