# JavaScript - Natural Sorting a FileList Object

Tags: javascript, natural-sort, filelist

I have a filelist object that contains over 1000 image files. I want the object to be sorted by file name, which is alphanumeric. In other words, I want to do a natural sort. The file names are like this:

```
d_1_ct.png
d_2_ct.png
d_3_ct.png
d_4_ct.png
```

Turning the filelist object into an array by doing `[].slice.call(filelist_object)` or `Array.from(filelist_object)` and then calling `sort()` results in alphabetical sort only. How can I make the filelist object naturally sorted on file name?

I am okay with turning it into an array, as long as I'm able to display the image files using `URL.createObjectURL()` on the array elements.

**Natural-sorting alphanumeric strings is not what I'm looking for**, though the names of my files in the filelist object *are* alphanumeric strings. The filelist object contains the following properties:

```
0: File
lastModified: 1493435514308
lastModifiedDate: Sat Apr 29 2017 08:41:54 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
name: "d_1_ct.png"
size: 5307
type: "image/png"
webkitRelativePath: "img/d_1_ct.png"
__proto__:File
```

I want to sort on either `name` or `webkitRelativePath`, while retaining all the properties of the filelist object, as I am using the index numbers of the object to display the images.

Comment: Think this might help you out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2802341/javascript-natural-sort-of-alphanumerical-strings

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript : natural sort of alphanumerical strings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2802341/javascript-natural-sort-of-alphanumerical-strings)

Comment: Updated to explain why it isn't a duplicate of natural sort of alphanumeric strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's now a much easier way using `localeCompare`: http://fuzzytolerance.info/blog/2019/07/19/The-better-way-to-do-natural-sort-in-JavaScript/

```
const items =  ['3rd', 'Apple', '24th', '99 in the shade', 'Dec', '10000', '101', '$1.23']
items.sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b, navigator.languages[0] || navigator.language, {numeric: true, ignorePunctuation: true}))
console.log(items)

// [ "$1.23", "3rd", "24th", "99 in the shade", "101", "10000", "Apple", "Dec" ]
```

Additionally, you can speed this up by [declaring the collator object beforehand](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52369951/700283).

Answer (score 6):

I first converted my filelist object into an array using `Array.from()`.

```
myArray = Array.from(myFileListObject);
```

Then, I used the `naturalCompare()` function written by Lauri Rooden. Here is the [GitHub link](https://github.com/litejs/natural-compare-lite).

I then called the `naturalCompare()` function on my array as follows:

```
myArray.sort(function(a,b) {
    return String.naturalCompare(a.name, b.name)
});
```

My array is now "naturally" sorted correctly. It still retains all the properties of the filelist object, so I am still able to use the `URL.createObjectURL()` method on its contents to display the images.

Comment: Please show how you use the  the URL.createObjectURL() method on the array contents to display the images.

Answer (score 0):

for a long time, i solved this for german "Umlaute" you can adapt this...

```
    function fhwSort(a, b){
       function fhwSplit(fstring){
          var mapObj = {
                ä:"ae",
                ö:"oe",
            ü:"ue",
            Ä:"ÄE",
            Ö:"ÖE",
            Ü:"UE",
            ß:"ss"
            };
          fstring = fstring.replace(/ä|ö|ü|Ä|ö|ü|ß/gi, function(matched){
                       return mapObj[matched];
                  });
          return fstring.toUpperCase().replace(/\d*/g, function (x) {
            return !x=="" ? '0'.repeat(20).substr(0,20-x.length)+x:'';});
       }
       a=fhwSplit(a["name"]);    
       b=fhwSplit(b["name"]);    
       return (a>b)+(a<b)*-1;
    }
    var data = [
       {name : "5.1. Test 3"},
       {name : "5.1. Test 1"},
       {name : "5.2. Test 2"},
       {name : "5.10. Test 10"},
       {name : "5.12. Test 12"},
       {name : "Karl"},
       {name : "Kader"},
       {name : "Käse"},
       {name : "Kuchen"}

       ];
    console.log("fhwSort");
    data.sort(fhwSort);
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
      console.log(data[i]["name"]);
    }
```

Comment: why space in `ß:"ss "`? why some replacements with `Ä:"ÄE:",` still some umlauts?