# localeCompare() vs .Sort for alphabetically sorting

Tags: javascript, performance, sorting

Im sorting an array of objects alphabetically but not sure which way is more efficient. Im currently using the .sort() method and its working fine but would using the localeCompare() be a better alternative?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14677060/400x-sorting-speedup-by-switching-a-localecompareb-to-ab-1ab10 may give you some ideas and examples

Comment: do you mean if may `localCompare()` be faster than using `a> b? 1: -1`?

Comment: do you care about valid ordering for 'A', 'a' and 'ä'?

Comment: yeah so would be better to do `a>b ?1:-1` or just use `localeCompare()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `localeCompare` function is absurdly slow on many browser. Avoid it if possible. The other locale functions are really bad too, particularly the number to string ones.